# Google Structured Data Name

Tags: html, structured-data

I have added structured data onto every page of my site like so:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "Your WebSite Name",
  "url": "http://www.your-site.com"
}
</script>
```

It's been live for about two weeks now, and I can test the page with the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) using the url and it fetches the structured data accurately.

Yet, when I search for my site, it doesn't replace the green url link with the name I specified in the structured data like the [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename) say it should.  How long will I need to wait before Google crawls my page and the results reflect the structured data? Or, is there something I need to do to summon their crawler?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Google *does not guarantee* that your structured data will show up in search results, even if your page is marked up correctly according to the Structured Data Testing Tool. The Google algorithm tailors search results to create what it thinks is the best search experience for a user, depending on many variables, including search history, location, and device type. In some cases it may determine that one feature is more appropriate than another, or even that a plain blue link is best.

Source: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Comment: I appreciate you for answering. I've since seen some of my structured data show up in results. Sometimes it doesn't though. I guess that's the best I can do.

Comment: It's Google's world; we only live in it. :)  I feel your pain, brother.