# How to fix Google search results showing URL instead of site name for WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

Site name not showing in search results, it shows URL instead

I have a strange problem, the URL is showing on Google search results instead of the website title in the area I have circled on the image below. Now, I understand this may be because the website title text on the actual website aflyontheball.com is also a link to the homepage. Is there a way to tell the HTML to no-index the URL while still indexing the text for my site's title?
[image: URL instead of site name image]

Because I am using a child theme, I am not sure how to edit the code directly in the header.php file because when I run the HTML source checker on my page, I can clearly see this code:

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header ">
  <div class="baby-container site-branding logo-center">
        
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="https://aflyontheball.com/" rel="home">FLY ON THE BALL</a></h1>
    <p class="site-description">SPORTS NEWS WITH A TWIST</p>
```

However, I cannot for the life of me find that code in the parent theme's header.php file. This is what I see:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header <?php if (has_header_image() && is_front_page()  && $x_blog_header_image_show == 'home-page') : ?>baby-head-img<?php endif; ?><?php if (has_header_image() && $x_blog_header_image_show == 'all-pages') : ?>baby-head-img<?php endif; ?>">
        <?php if (has_header_image()) : ?>
            <?php if ((has_header_image() && $x_blog_header_image_show == 'all-pages') || (has_header_image() && is_front_page() && $x_blog_header_image_show == 'home-page')) : ?>
                <div class="header-img">
                    <?php the_header_image_tag(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php do_action('xblog_site_title'); ?>
        <?php do_action('xblog_main_menubar'); ?>
```

Meanwhile, in my index.php I can see this:

```
if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
```

Perhaps I am not even on the correct trail. This has been bothering the crap out of me and I want to figure it out. I am such a noob to coding but I'm trying my best to teach myself through trial and error but this one has me stumped.

Another possibility is the content.php file where I can see this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php x_blog_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <div class="baby-feature-image"> 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        $xblog_content_type = get_theme_mod( 'xblog_content_type', 'full' );
        if($post->post_excerpt && !is_single() || $xblog_content_type == 'short' && !is_single() ){ 
            the_excerpt();
            echo sprintf('<div class="redmore-btn"><a href="%s" class="more-link" rel="bookmark">'. esc_html__('Continue Reading','x-blog').the_title('<span class="screen-reader-text">"','"</span>', false).'</a></div>', esc_url(get_permalink()));
        }else{ 
            the_content( sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'x-blog' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                get_the_title()
            ) );
        }
            

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'x-blog' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If I simply delete the  part of the index.php, will that solve my home page issue but will it also affect the individual post SEO titles in Google search results?

Comment: Sorting out problems like this is hard, because changes you make on your site can take days, or longer, to show up in search results. Do you have one of the [SEO plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/seo/) on your site? The popular ones have developers with expertise in this sort of thing.

Comment: I am currently using RankMath on this site, the free version of RankMath. I have this same problem on another site, darkconfessional.com, which is using Yoast along with a different theme. I have explored both of the SEO plugins extensively without any solution. 

I understand it will take a while to show up in search results, but I just have not been able to figure out where to even start trying.

Comment: RankMath (along with other SEO plugins) generates a [sitemap](https://sitemap.org).  Yours is at `https://aflyontheball.com/sitemap.xml`. Google and the other search engine spiders use it to drive their indexing.  You might address your question to RankMath support; maybe they can suggest something. Also, your site title lacks the initial `a` of your domain name.

Comment: I submitted a question to RankMath but somehow I think the solution lies elsewhere. Hopefully they can help me though. Again though, I have this problem on two different sites using two different SEO plugins and two different themes. I somehow believe this can be fixed via code editing.

Answer (score 0):

This information is retrieved form the structured data. The docuumentation may be found here: [Search Result Site Names](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names)

Note though that there is no guarantee this will show up: [Structured Data Not Showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498198/google-structured-data-name).